# Numeric sort an array with mixed types values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a mixed array like this:

```
$fruits = array(
    "lemon",
    "Lemon",
    20,
    "banana",
    "apple",
    "121",
    40,
    50
);
```

And then apply `sort()` function to it as follows:

```
sort($fruits, SORT_NUMERIC);
foreach ($fruits as $key => $val) {
    echo "fruits[" . $key . "] = " . $val . "\n";
}
```

Now, i do not understand the output that is:

```
fruits[0] = apple
fruits[1] = lemon
fruits[2] = banana
fruits[3] = Lemon
fruits[4] = 20
fruits[5] = 40
fruits[6] = 50
fruits[7] = 121
```

Please explain why it is sorted that way?

Comment: What does the mixed array _actually_ contain? There is probably a way to separate the numeric and string data.

Comment: this question is for my curiosity on sort() function

Answer (score 3):

OP, since [`sort();`](https://www.php.net/sort) doesn't work so well with uppercase and lowercase characters, why don't you convert everything to lowercase then sort?

```
<?php
$fruits = array("lemon","Lemon", 20, "banana", "apple","121",40,50);
$fruits = array_map("strtolower", $fruits); //using strtolower

sort($fruits );
foreach ($fruits as $key => $val) {
    echo "fruits[" . $key . "] = " . $val . "\n";
}
?>
```

Outputs

```
fruits[0] = 20
fruits[1] = 40
fruits[2] = 50
fruits[3] = 121
fruits[4] = apple
fruits[5] = banana
fruits[6] = lemon
fruits[7] = lemon
```

Answer (score 2):

basically it should sort from A to Z then by numeric order, but using mixed type the function do not know how to sort the array and give a random result...

in the manual page there is a huge warning says that:

> Be careful when sorting arrays with mixed types values because sort()
> can produce unpredictable results.

you can add a parameter to the function:

- SORT_REGULAR - compare items normally (don't change types)
- SORT_NUMERIC - compare items numerically
- SORT_STRING - compare items as strings
- SORT_LOCALE_STRING - compare items as strings, based on the current locale. Added in PHP 4.4.0 and 5.0.2, it uses the system locale, which can be changed using setlocale().

According to manual [here](https://www.php.net/sort) on php.net

**Edit 1:**
Probably you can obtain the best sort result using the flag `SORT_REGULAR` because it does not change the variable type and numbers remain numbers and strings remain strings but it will also give you a strange result

```
fruits[0] = 121
fruits[1] = Lemon
fruits[2] = apple
fruits[3] = banana
fruits[4] = lemon
fruits[5] = 20
fruits[6] = 40
fruits[7] = 50
```

I think because it compare the ascii code from the letters of strings and `L` is before `a b l`...
121 is in first place because you wrote it like a string `"121"`

**Edit 2:**

The best way to proceed is to separate the types: (this way php will treat "121" as a number and not a string, but you can simply decide it by the `if` clause)

```
<?php
$fruits = array("lemon","Lemon", 20, "banana", "apple","121",40,50);
$arr1=array();
$arr2=array();
      foreach($fruits as $key=>$val){
          if (is_numeric($val))
               array_push($arr1,$val); 
          else
              array_push($arr2,$val);
      }          
sort($arr1,SORT_NUMERIC);            
sort($arr2,SORT_LOCALE_STRING);
$fruits = array_merge($arr1,$arr2);
echo "<pre>";
foreach ($fruits as $key => $val) {
    echo "fruits[" . $key . "] = " . $val . "\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: Regardless of what the sort flag is, it still messes up with "Lemon" and "lemon"

Comment: yeah, I edited the post, in the manual page there is an explicict warning about sorting mixed types array, can cause an unpredictable results, I think because the function do not know how to sort the array (by string or by numeric order)

Comment: probably the best way to sort that array is to use the flag `SORT_REGULAR` but it will give a strange result itself because it won't sort correctly the strings (`Lemon` before `apple` and before `lemon`) due to ascii char value...

Comment: I think SORT_REGULAR is ordering by the ASCII table.

Answer (score 1):

I believe with [`sort($array, SORT_NUMERIC)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php), the values that cannot be converted to a number are treated as `0` and sorted that way. Since all strings in your example become 0 it really does not matter at all whether **lemon** comes before **banana**. Here is an example:

```
<?php
$fruits = array("alpha", "bravo", -1, -0.001, 0, 0.001, 1, "x-ray", "zulu");
shuffle($fruits); // randomly re-arrange the items in array
sort($fruits, SORT_NUMERIC);
print_r($fruits);
// output -- pass 1
Array
(
    [0] => -1
    [1] => -0.001
    [2] => 0
    [3] => alpha
    [4] => x-ray
    [5] => zulu
    [6] => bravo
    [7] => 0.001
    [8] => 1
)
// output -- pass 2
Array
(
    [0] => -1
    [1] => -0.001
    [2] => bravo
    [3] => zulu
    [4] => 0
    [5] => x-ray
    [6] => alpha
    [7] => 0.001
    [8] => 1
)
// output -- pass 3
Array
(
    [0] => -1
    [1] => -0.001
    [2] => x-ray
    [3] => zulu
    [4] => 0
    [5] => bravo
    [6] => alpha
    [7] => 0.001
    [8] => 1
)
?>
```