# Why does SORT_REGULAR produce inconsistent results in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I'm working on a class which makes sorting of arrays easier in PHP and I've been playing with the SORT_ constants, however the behaviour or `SORT_REGULAR` (the default sort type) seems to differ depending what order you add the items in your array. Moreover, I can't spot a pattern as to why this might be the case.

**Array items:**

```
$a = '0.3';
$b = '.5';
$c = '4';
$d = 'F';
$e = 'z';
$f = 4;
```

**Scenario 1:**

```
sort(array($d, $e, $a, $f, $b, $c));

// Produces...
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "0.3"
  [1]=>
  string(2) ".5"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "4"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "F"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "z"
  [5]=>
  int(4)
}
```

**Scenario 2:**

```
sort(array($d, $e, $b, $f, $c, $a));

// Produces...
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "0.3"
  [1]=>
  string(2) ".5"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "F"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "z"
  [4]=>
  int(4)
  [5]=>
  string(1) "4"
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: @hakre: it's about transitivity of comparison function/operator used for the given sorting strategy, not about stability

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://php.net/sort

> Warning
>
> Be careful when sorting arrays with mixed types values because sort()
>   can produce unpredictable results.

You should use one of the SORT_* constants.

There are a few comments here:

- [Numeric sort an array with mixed types values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955651/numeric-sort-a-mixed-types-values-array-by-sort-php-function)
- [PHP turtles](http://quaxio.com/wtf/php.html#turtle17)

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually writing a unit test to ensure the sorting class replicates the native PHP algorithm and that's how I stumbled across the problem. Every time I changed the input the order of the expected output changed! I'll put it down to "one of those things".

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is "expected" (or at least known) because you use different types for the values (strings and integers). See the manual of the [`sort()`](http://www.php.net/sort) function.

> **Warning**
>
> Be careful when sorting arrays with mixed types values because sort() can produce unpredictable results.

It is most likely that, at some point in the sorting algorithm, it compares two values as integers and not as strings. To avoid this situation don't try to sort arrays with different types (as the manual say).

Comment: Thanks... interesting explanation. I don't know much about the internals but I guessed everything would be compared to everything else and therefore you would expect consistent results no matter what the order of input was but that;s obviously not the case.

Answer (score 2):

### SORT_REGULAR is like `<`.

It seems that `SORT_REGULAR` follows the same rules as the `<` operator (and thus, the `>` operator).

In my own tests, for any two values $v0 and $v1, the following assertion did pass:

```
$pair = [$v0, $v1];
sort($pair);
assert($pair[0] < $pair[1]);
```

### With mixed types, `<` is not a strict weak order.

Unfortunately, `<` with a mix of strings and integers has a circular behavior, and is not transitive. Thus, it is not a [Strict weak order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings)

This can be shown by the following assertions, which [pass](https://3v4l.org/oNB3T):

```
assert('3' < '10');    // Numeric comparison. 2 < 12.
assert('10' < '2 ');  // Lexicographical comparison
// Circular:
assert('2 ' < '3');   // Lexicographical comparison
// Not transitive:
assert(!('3' < '2 '));   // Lexicographical comparison

// And just because it's interesting:
assert('2 ' < 3);    // Numeric comparison. 2 < 3.
```

The idea of sorting is that in the sorted list of items, if `$i < $j`, then `!($sorted_items[$j] < $sorted_items[$i])`.

This is only possible if `<` is a strict total order, or a strict weak order.

### Sometimes, `<` reads strings as numbers.

The following rules seem to apply for `<`:

- If both values are strings that "look like" (*) numbers, numeric comparison applies.
- If one value *is* a number, numeric comparison applies.
- If both values are strings and at least one of them does not look like a   number, alphabetic (lexicographic) comparison applies.

(*) The string '4' does "look like" the number 4. The string '4 x' does not "look like" the number 4, but `(int)'4 x'` still evaluates to 4.

### The original example

The sort in this specific example is actually consistent in PHP 7, just not in PHP 5.*, as can be seen [here](https://3v4l.org/iU6nt).

This does not mean that PHP 7 is immune to this problem. It just happens to be ok in this specific example.

Comparing the individual values [reveals](https://3v4l.org/P288c):

hhvm-3.9.1 - 3.12.0, 7.0.0 - 7.1.0alpha2

```
'0.3' < '.5'
'0.3' < '4'
'0.3' < 'F'
'0.3' < 'z'
'0.3' < 4
'.5' < '4'
'.5' < 'F'
'.5' < 'z'
'.5' < 4
'4' < 'F'
'4' < 'z'
'4' < 4
'F' < 'z'
'F' < 4
'z' < 4
```

5.5.0 - 5.6.23

```
'0.3' < '.5'
'0.3' < '4'
'0.3' < 'F'
'0.3' < 'z'
'0.3' < 4
'.5' < '4'
'.5' < 'F'
'.5' < 'z'
'.5' < 4
'4' < 'F'
'4' < 'z'
4 < '4'
'F' < 'z'
'F' < 4
'z' < 4
```

Now let's remove the boring bits.

- '0.3' is smaller than everything else, and thus not part of any circle.
- '.5' is smaller than everything else (after removing '0.3'), and thus not part of any circle.

In PHP 7:

- '4' is smaller than everything else, and thus not part of any circle.
- 4 is bigger than everything else, and thus not part of any circle.
- `'F' < 'z'` remains. Nothing circular. Hence, there is exactly one sort order possible: `['0.3', '.5', '4', 'F', 'z', 4]`.

In PHP 5.*:

There are multiple ways to build circles with these results.

One such circle is: `'4' < 'F'`, `'F' < 4`, `4 < '4'`.

This means: In any sort order, there will be at least two positions `$i` and `$j` with `$i < $j` but `$sorted[$j] < $sorted[$i]`.